# image copy in android doesn't work?

Tags: android, clipboard

I am trying to implement image copy to clipboard functionality in android 14 and higher. I checked the api(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) and implemented the following code:

```
 String filename = mApplication.getHistoryJNI().getActiveImagePath();
    ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "Image/png");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filename);
    ContentResolver theContent = getContentResolver();
    Uri imageUri = theContent.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Image", imageUri);
    mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
```

And when I want to past I see content://media/external/images/media/120 resource path.
I know, the apps should support the image past functionality and I tried to past in Polaris office which supports pasting, but it doesn't work.

All suggestions and comments are appreciated.

Comment: Hi @David_O did you find any solution to your problem. I am stuck at the same point.

Comment: @Nibs no, its not possible still. Apps which do that, use hidden API provided by Samsung for example, so it's not original OS feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. @David_O is it because the app where u pasting did not support image or that it cant be done.

Comment: @Nibs Both, OS and app should support. For example, Samsung changes the OS and passes the hidden API to Polaris office. So, Polaris implements code to support image past feature.